# routing with language in Angular + Typescript VS Code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am developing a multi-language Angular4 application with VS Code.

The router has to be like this:

> localhost/en-us/visions

I have a class called TranslateHelper:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
export class TranslateHelper {
   private currentLanguage: string;
   private defaultLanguage = 'de-de';

   constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

   public getCurrentLanguage() {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.currentLanguage = params.lang;
   });

   return this.currentLanguage;
  }
}
```

the app-routing.module is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':lang/visions', component: VisionsComponent},
];
```

and in the footer I am trying to add the language in the URL:

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  public lang;

  constructor(private translateHelper: TranslateHelper) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lang = this.translateHelper.getCurrentLanguage();
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
    <li><a [routerLink]="[lang, 'visions']">Visions</a></li>
```

I do not receive any failure, but the lang in the footer is always undefined, exactly as the params.lang is.

can anybody tell me how can I fix it? thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your return is outside of your subscribe. Try putting it inside.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? I did not understand your answer

Comment: `return this.currentLanguage` should be inside the subscribe, just a couple of lines above

Comment: That won't work either so don't bother. You can't return something from a subscription.

Comment: It can, if you directly return the subscribe statement

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return something from within a subscription, that won't really work. Either you can return the route params and subscribe to that in your component or you can do it like this:

```
export class TranslateHelper {
   private currentLanguage: string;
   private defaultLanguage = 'de-de';

   private language: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

   public language$ = language.asObservable();

   constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

   public getCurrentLanguage() {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.language.next(params.lang)
      });
   }
}


export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  public lang;

  constructor(private translateHelper: TranslateHelper) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.translateHelper.language$.subscribe(language => {
      this.lang = language;
    }):
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you, but still not working. I did your solution. still undefined. 
can you please provide me with some explanation so I can understand

Comment: Basically you create an observable which your component subscribes to, and you emit a value inside the subscribe call. If that is all it's going to do you should just grab the parameter directly in the component tbh without the helper. As it just adds more code for no reason really.

Comment: I tried to write the routing with the subscription directly in the component, but still undefined.

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.lang = params.lang;
    });

Comment: @SamySammour Then you're probably in the wrong route trying to fetch it. Try adding a `parent`, `this.route.parent.params...`

Comment: @SamySammour Can you make a plunkr? Then I can solve it.

Comment: I guess I added all the necessary files. it won't work on a plunkr but will in vs code if you download it and add it to an empty angular project:
https://plnkr.co/edit/b9WEm1YbUg8GlhI9mUvw?p=linter